# How can I have my .net core 2.1 web app listen on 2 ports

Tags: docker, kestrel, .net-core-2.1

I have a .net core 2.1 web service that I'm trying to get set up with run with Docker. I'm trying to expose my App Metrics health checks on port 8081 and the rest of my web service api on port 80.

When I do a docker build and run on my dotnet publish folder, I'm getting the following error. What's the proper way to do this?

```
Hosting /metrics on port 8081
Hosting /metrics-text endpoint on port 8081
Hosting /env endpoint on port 8081
Configured platform region: us-west-2
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
    No XML encryptor configured. Key {d1abbb8a-2891-46d5-949b-0716020eb2a0} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
    Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.ParseAddress(String address, Boolean& https)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
    Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.ParseAddress(String address, Boolean& https)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.ParseAddress(String address, Boolean& https)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
at EmailService.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Here's my setup...

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80,http://+8081
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
EXPOSE 80 8081
```

**Program.cs**

```
using App.Metrics;
using App.Metrics.AspNetCore;
using App.Metrics.AspNetCore.Health;
using App.Metrics.Formatters.Prometheus;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace MyService
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
            //args run loop 
        }
        public static IMetricsRoot Metrics { get; set; }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            Metrics = AppMetrics.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .OutputMetrics.AsPrometheusPlainText()
                .Build();

            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureMetrics(Metrics)
                .UseMetrics(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.EndpointOptions = endpointsOptions =>
                {
                            endpointsOptions.MetricsTextEndpointOutputFormatter = new MetricsPrometheusTextOutputFormatter(); 
                        };
                    }
                )
                .ConfigureAppMetricsHostingConfiguration(options =>
                {
                    options.AllEndpointsPort = 8081;
                    options.MetricsEndpoint = "/metrics";
                })
                .ConfigureAppHealthHostingConfiguration(options =>
                {
                    options.HealthEndpoint = "/healthcheck";
                    options.PingEndpoint = "/ping";
                })
                .UseHealthEndpoints(options => { options.HealthEndpointOutputFormatter = new Core.HealthChecks.HealthCheckStatusFormatter(); })
                .UseHealth()
                .UseMetricsEndpoints()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you have the answer to this please? I would like to listen on multiple SSL ports.